# Is there any way to know which user is using the Access database in VB

Tags: database, vb.net

I got a VB program. It's to use Access database to manage project information. The program could be used by users from different PCs. I understand the PC's current username could be get from

```
UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
```

I just want to display this username when program starts, for example, just display a message box with the information "XXX is accessing the database".

The database connection I am using is OleDbConnection, the source I open the database is

```
Private Const DB_PROVIDER As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
Private Const DB_SOURCE As String = "Data Source=\\meldc2\X-Drive\Luxi\NSW_OLGR.accdb"
Private Const DB_MODE As String = "Mode=Share Exclusive"
Private Const DB_CONNECTION_STRING As String = DB_PROVIDER + ";" + DB_SOURCE + ";" + DB_MODE

mConnection = New OleDbConnection
mConnection.ConnectionString = DB_CONNECTION_STRING

mConnection.Open()
```

So my question is "IS THERE ANY API ON THIS CONNECTION TO GET THE SAME USERNAME AS ABOVE?". I found the Open() API could throw an exception if the database is under use. Can I get some information about username from the exception?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, but I find if I open the database file by double-click directly, there is a lock file with the content of PC identification and username. Can OleDbConnection do that in a similar way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your app is not handling the login - if the "lock file" is an Access LogIn dialog it would appear that there is some level of security applied.  But since you have the USER entering the info (all that can be handled by the app instead), you are not going to get it back from the Connection string...or from the DB.

The really easy way to report DB activity would be from the VB app accessing it.  When your app opens the connection, use `UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName` or `Environment.UserName` to  do something.

A) Send a network message including the username to whereever the MessageBox is supposed to display.

B) After opening the connection and DB the app could make an entry to a new ActivityLog table.  If it is worth reporting via a msgbox, it might be worth keeping a record of.  Similarly, when the connection/DB is closed, an Exit type entry could be logged.

The name you use might not match the Access Login name, but it will certainly identify a user.
Whoever is going to monitor it could just leave Access open to that table open to watch.  Or as I mentioned, write a small applet on a timer which watches for new entries to the log table.

HTH

Comment: I have tried to add "Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;" to connection string, and I found there could generate the .laccdb file, which contains host name and username of the connection. The problem now is how to get information from the .laccdb file properly. Thanks, Plutonix

Comment: doesnt that require you to put `User ID=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword;` in the connection string?